# Node.js unit testing using redis-mock

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, unit-testing

I am trying to connect to redis and set the data in redis using [redis-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-mock) library in node-typescript but the test is failing

The redis connection code:

```
let client: RedisClientType;

client = createClient({
    url: "redis://localhost:6379",
});

beforeAll(() => {
    async () => {
        try {
            await client.connect();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error connecting redis');
        }
    };
});
```

I have configured the redis-mock in jest.config.js file as per the `redis-mock` documentation but somehow it is not working

Here is the test case:

```
describe('Redis', () => {
    it('should set user info in Redis', async () => {
        const userInfo = { id: 1, name: 'John Doe' };
        const token = 'some-token';

        await client.set(token, JSON.stringify(userInfo));
        const result = await client.get(token);

        expect(result).toEqual(JSON.stringify(userInfo));
    });
});
```

The return value of redis set method returns undefined

Comment: What version of Redis are you using?

Comment: Do you mean the return value of `await client.get(token)` is `undefined`?

Comment: @LinDu It is not connecting, so get and set don't matter. pardon for mis-information in my question

Comment: @RimonFedyuk redis version is 7 and redis package version is 4.6

Answer (score 0):

redis-mock get & set methods required a callback function.
see example here: https://github.com/yeahoffline/redis-mock/blob/master/test/client/redis-mock.set.test.js#L517

```js
jest.mock('redis', () => jest.requireActual('redis-mock'));

const redis = require( 'redis' );
const client = redis.createClient();

describe( 'Redis', () => {
   it( 'should set user info in Redis', ( done ) => {
      const userInfo = { id: 1, name: 'John Doe' };
      const token = 'some-token';
      client.set( token, JSON.stringify( userInfo ), () => {
         client.get( token, ( err, result ) => {
            expect( result ).toEqual( JSON.stringify( userInfo ) );
            done();
         } );
      } );
   } );
} );
```